# is prisoners not being able to vote and disenfranchisement a major reason for why there is a lack of lobbying in criminal justice reform?

Tags: crime

Most of the lobbying on criminal justice reforms seems to be more towards the side of bringing more "tough on crime" and "zero tolerance" policies. there isn't much of a movement in terms of criminal justice reform that aims to bring about non retributive measures. is it because people who are in prison cannot addequately represent themselves ? what can be done to change this ?

Comment: *more "tough on crime" and "zero tolerance" policies* What are you basing this claim on - can you provide links?  It may not be moving quickly but I kinda got the sense things were, overall, heading in the opposite direction.  And shouldn't you tag this `United States`?

Comment: You also have plenty of sensationalism about things like the crime rate is going up and how bad crime is. When people see things like that they have less of a desire to change things.

Comment: This question basically asks "If there was no disenfranchisement and prisoners were able to vote, there would be more lobbying in criminal justice reform." So, I vote to close it as hypothetical.

Comment: why are hypothetical questions not alowed ? @SJuan76

Comment: @IndianLawApplicant because they cannot be answered with any kind of certainty. Answers would be based on speculation, guesswork and opinion. Sociological developments are notoriously hard to model/predict. You can compare to other countries, but there are usually too many differences to show causality.

Comment: This question needs some serious work to improve. It seems like it could be US specific, but without a specific jurisdiction there is no way to answer this question. Further, it isn't really specific on what reform its seeking. The question itself admits lobbying for criminal justice reform, but appears to be dissatisfied with the type of reform being lobbied. The question would be helped by being more specific in what it is actually seeking. Currently, this is more of a complaint about the type of lobbying rather than a question about the lack of lobbying.

Comment: Which jurisdiction are you thinking of, please?

Comment: North America and to an extent Canada

Comment: Which jurisdiction are you referring to specifically? There is no tag to narrow the scope of question.

Answer (score 3):

While the [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felony_disenfranchisement_in_the_United_States) of disenfranchised people in the US is large in absolute terms, the percentage is not high enough to completely overturn voter demographics. There may be some [swing states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_state) where  they could tip the balance, but the traditional voter apathy and hurdles to voter registration keep more citizens from the polls.

Comment: is voting the only effective way of bringing reform or incentivising people to act for reform in this area ?

Comment: @TDUsolarcrownHype, my answer posits that the voting power is not enough to make a difference. As to what to do about the problem, *if it is a problem*, that is a different question. Countries develop attitudes on things like this which can be influenced by political spin, but which are also taught from generation to generation.

Comment: is it a problem in your opinion and if so what are some ways of solving it ?

Comment: @TDUsolarcrownHype, I believe that it is a problem when it comes to ex-convicts, and that it is impossible to solve in the political climate. One option would be to require courts to pass the loss of voting rights as a *separate* punishment rather than automatic, but making this change would be very low on the list of needed reforms.

Comment: is there any specific reason why it is impossible to solve in the political climate ? what things should reform focus on in your opinion ?

Comment: @TDUsolarcrownHype, the Republicans believe that if ex-convicts were given the vote, they would mostly not vote Republican. Which means that fundamental change is not going to happen anytime soon.

Comment: is grassroots democracy a viable option in places where certain sections aren't allowed to vote or have their voice heard ? @o.m.

Comment: @TDUsolarcrownHype, no. Grassroots democracy is about *voter mobilization.*

Answer (score 1):

I assume this question is about united states. One problem here is private prisons.

The business model encourage lobbyism. The solution could be only to have public prisons.